# Make custom intermediate (improve C compilable tester) in CMake

Tags: c++, c, cmake

So we have mixed C++/C projects. I want to enforce that, even if all source files are .cpp (C++ compiled) that source files with the "*.h" extension are C compileable (using *.hpp for C++ only files). I'd like to enforce it at compile time, such that the build returns an error (associated with the project, with full line numbers and C error and warnings). Running at configure time is (imho) achieves limited results.

So I currently have a script that will do that:

```make
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

MACRO(MAKE_C_COMPILE_TESTER project_name target_sources cvar)

SET(CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT "")

FOREACH(src ${target_sources})
      MESSAGE(STATUS "TESTING src ${src}")
      GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(SRC_EXT "${src}" EXT)
      MESSAGE(STATUS "SRC_EXT=${SRC_EXT}")
      if("${SRC_EXT}" STREQUAL ".h")
          set(CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT "${CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT}\n#include \"${src}\"")
      endif()
ENDFOREACH()

set(${cvar} "${${project_name}_BINARY_DIR}/${project_name}_CCompileTest.c")

configure_file("${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeConfigurableFile.in"
  "${${cvar}}"
  @ONLY)
set_source_files_properties("${cvar}" PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)

ENDMACRO()
```

USAGE:

```make
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

INCLUDE(MAKE_C_COMPILE_TESTER.cmake)

project(playlib)
add_definitions(-DPLAY_LIB_EXPORTS)

SET(${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC_LIST play_lib.h play_lib.hpp play_lib.cpp test.c testlib.h)

MAKE_C_COMPILE_TESTER(${PROJECT_NAME} "${${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC_LIST}" ${PROJECT_NAME}_CTESTER)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC_LIST} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_CTESTER})
```

This works, but is a little more invasive than I want. It requires multiple lines, and if the SRC_LIST isn't a single variable than you may have more work than you want. In addition, it adds the .c file which could be confusing to people.

What I'd prefer is that I build ${project_name}_CCompileTest.c as an intermediate: it is not included as a source file in the directory, and can be added as a single line to existing files. Something like:

```make
SET(${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC_LIST play_lib.h play_lib.hpp play_lib.cpp test.c testlib.h)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC_LIST})
MAKE_C_COMPILE_TESTER(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

This way it can be quickly added to all existing projects as well as future projects. I know I can extract the source list using `GET_TARGET_PROPERTIES(var ${project_name} SOURCES)`, and I think is can do it with ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET ${project_name})...but I don't know how to do it in a cross-platform, dependency-efficient way. Any ideas how to compile a C file to a `.o` or `.i` without linking or including the source file in the project?

Edit: possible solution path that I haven't figured out completely yet (so obviously, the following code does not work):

```make
  SET(MYCOMPILE "${CMAKE_C_COMPILE_OBJECT}")

  STRING(REGEX REPLACE "<CMAKE_C_COMPILER>" "\"\${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}\"" MYCOMPILE "${MYCOMPILE}")

  #STRING(REGEX REPLACE "<FLAGS>" "\${FLAGS}" MYCOMPILE "${MYCOMPILE}")
  STRING(REGEX REPLACE  ">" "}" MYCOMPILE "${MYCOMPILE}")
  STRING(REGEX REPLACE  "<" "\${" MYCOMPILE "${MYCOMPILE}")



  SET(MYCOMPILE "MACRO(ADD_COMPILE_FILE_COMMAND SOURCE)
  GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(SOURCE_BASE_NAME \"${SOURCE}\" NAME_WE)
  SET(FLAGS
   \"\$<\$<CONFIG:None>:\${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}>\$<\$<CONFIG:Debug>:\${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG}>\$<\$<CONFIG:Release>:\${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}>\$<\$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:\${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO}>\$<\$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:\${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL}>\"
   )
  SET(OBJECT \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${SOURCE_BASE_NAME}.o\")

  GET_PROPERTY(${PROJECT_NAME}_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_NONE DIRECTORY \${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
  GET_PROPERTY(${PROJECT_NAME}_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG DIRECTORY \${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG)
  GET_PROPERTY(${PROJECT_NAME}_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE DIRECTORY \${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE)
  GET_PROPERTY(${PROJECT_NAME}_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELWITHDEBINFO DIRECTORY \${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELWITHDEBINFO)
  GET_PROPERTY(${PROJECT_NAME}_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_MINSIZEREL DIRECTORY \${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_MINSIZEREL)
  SET (DEFINES
  \"\$<\$<CONFIG:None>:\${PROJECT_NAME}_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_NONE>\$<\$<CONFIG:Debug>:\${PROJECT_NAME}_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG>\$<\$<CONFIG:Release>:\${PROJECT_NAME}_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE>\$<\$<CONFIG:RelWithDebInfo>:\${PROJECT_NAME}_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELWITHDEBINFO>\$<\$<CONFIG:MinSizeRel>:\${PROJECT_NAME}_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_MINSIZEREL>\")
  ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}
    COMMAND \"\${CMAKE_COMMAND}\" -E echo \"*******\${\${DEFINES}}\")
  ADD_CUSTOM_COMMAND(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${MYCOMPILE}
    )

ENDMACRO()
  ")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "MYCOMPILE=${MYCOMPILE}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "CMAKE_C_COMPILER=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
  GET_PROPERTY(COMPILE_DEFINITIONS DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "COMPILE_DEFINITIONS=${COMPILE_DEFINITIONS}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG=${COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_DEBUG}")
  GET_PROPERTY(COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" PROPERTY COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE)
  MESSAGE(STATUS "COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE=${COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELEASE}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELWITHDEBINFO=${COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_RELWITHDEBINFO}")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_MINSIZEREL =${COMPILE_DEFINITIONS_MINSIZEREL}")

  set(CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT ${MYCOMPILE})
  CONFIGURE_FILE("${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeConfigurableFile.in"
  "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/cbuild.cmake"
  )

  INCLUDE("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/cbuild.cmake")
  ADD_COMPILE_FILE_COMMAND("${${PROJECT_NAME}_CTESTER}")
```

Basically, the idea is to look up the C compile command and then actually use it. But it is a nightmare getting all the variables set correctly in a non-make style generator (I'm currently trying to get it to work with Visual Studio, though a cross platform solution is required).

Comment: +1 for using different extensions for C and C++ header files.

Comment: +1: For using "*.hpp" extension to cpp headers files, even that many programers, don't use it. When you open your O.S. File browser, it's good to see that "*.hpp" files are meant for C++ programming, and, not just some unknown data files ...

Answer (score 4):

I didn't really follow your question, but regarding:

```
Any ideas how to compile a C file to a .o or .i without linking 
or including the source file in the project?
```

see OBJECT libraries.

http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html

Comment: hrm...I'd rather not clutter the project with additional targets. In addition, failures will show up as part of the OBJECT library not the target lib. Still, +1 for a viable solution.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following macro:

```
MACRO(MAKE_C_COMPILE_TESTER LIBRARY)

# Get the sources LIBRARY consists of:
get_target_property(FILES ${LIBRARY} SOURCES)

SET(HEADERS_TO_USE "")

FOREACH(file ${FILES})
  GET_FILENAME_COMPONENT(FILE_EXT "${file}" EXT)
  if ("${FILE_EXT}" STREQUAL ".h")
     LIST(APPEND HEADERS_TO_USE ${file})
  endif()
ENDFOREACH()

SET(COMPILE_INPUT "")

FOREACH(header ${HEADERS_TO_USE})
  MESSAGE(STATUS "FOUND C header ${header}")
  SET(COMPILE_INPUT "${COMPILE_INPUT}\n #include \"${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${header}\"")
ENDFOREACH()

INCLUDE(CheckCSourceCompiles)
CHECK_C_SOURCE_COMPILES("#include<stdio.h> 

${COMPILE_INPUT}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 
  printf(\"Hello World\"); 
  return 0;
}" C_INCLUDE_CHECK)

IF (${C_INCLUDE_CHECK} MATCHES "1")
  MESSAGE(STATUS "C_INCLUDE_CHECK: success.")
ELSE()
  message(SEND_ERROR "C_INCLUDE_CHECK: FAIL, check log.")
ENDIF()

ENDMACRO(MAKE_C_COMPILE_TESTER)
```

I noticed that you add libraries. So I get the list of files for a target (like a library) and check that a C hello world which includes the .h files can compile using a C compiler.

The CMakeLists.txt where it is being used is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8)

INCLUDE(MAKE_C_COMPILE_TESTER.cmake)

project(playlib)
add_definitions(-DPLAY_LIB_EXPORTS)

include_directories(include)

# Works, only cpp/hpp c/h files.
#add_library(MIXEDTESTLIB SHARED include/lib1.h include/lib2.hpp src/lib1.c src/lib2.cpp)

# Will not work, cpp/h files, header which cannot compile using C compiler.
add_library(MIXEDTESTLIB SHARED include/lib1.h include/lib2.hpp include/lib3.h src/lib1.c src/lib2.cpp src/lib3.cpp)

MAKE_C_COMPILE_TESTER(MIXEDTESTLIB)
```

I tested this macro on Linux, but I assume that it will work on other platforms and with other generators. If not then at least you can be inspired. :)

An example project can be downloaded from:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68798379/cmake-c-cpp-header-check.tar.bz2

Comment: Won't this only run @configure time, not at compile time (eg if I change lib1.h after configuring so it is no longer C compilable, it'll still pass?) You can't call it as a custom command, because the configuration variables will no longer be set...

Comment: Yes, as I assumed that it was what you wanted. 

If you setup Jenkins (or whatever you are using) to re-configure each time there is a commit you get the same check with blaming on the person who broke your build.

Comment: I'd rather it be checked at compile time, so that bad commits are never made in the first place. I'll edit my question.

Comment: (+1 thanks for the repose though, the try_compile round would be much easier).

Comment: Just FYI, i tried to run this as a script in a custom command (in conjunction with a few other bad ideas), but "Command try_compile() is not scriptable" :-/

Comment: What you are trying to do is IMHO not supported by CMake in any graceful way (I don't find executing custom commands as part of a build graceful because of the added complexity). I think that these kinds of tests are meant to be executed when you configure the SW - just as it would be with autoconf/automake. Have you thought about a pre-commit hook which should check that some property of your source if OK before it allows you to commit?

Comment: Yeah...i think you're probably right. Unfortunately, we don't currently support such hooks, but it is probably the correct way to go. (If no one comes up with anything that exactly fits my question, I'll give you the bounty when it is about to expire).

Answer (score 0):

Usually *.h files are compiled by themselves but are included in other c/cpp files. When you include a file all of it's contents are then added to the original file and thus the compilation it undergoes will match that of the file, so if you compile a *.cpp file with c++ compiler and that file includes a *.h file you don't have much to do except change the compilation to C compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution I came up with. The idea is that `make_c_compile_tester` is now a function that generates a CMake file tailored to generate your C file that include the C headers, and generates a target that trigger the processing of this file.

I started with the usage you sought:

```
include(make_c_compile_tester.cmake)
project(playlib)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC_LIST play_lib.h play_lib.hpp play_lib.cpp test.c testlib.h dummy.h)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${${PROJECT_NAME}_SRC_LIST})
make_c_compile_tester(${PROJECT_NAME})
```

I moved the code you gave that generates the `${project_name}_CCompileTest.c` in a CMake template `check_ext.cmake.in`:

```
function(check_ext target_name test_file source_dir sources_list)
  set(CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT "")
  foreach(_src_file ${sources_list} ${ARGN})
    get_filename_component(_src_ext "${source_dir}/${_src_file}" EXT)
    if("${_src_ext}" STREQUAL ".h")
      set(CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT "${CMAKE_CONFIGURABLE_FILE_CONTENT}\n#include \"${source_dir}/${_src_file}\"")
    endif()
  endforeach()
  set(_check_file "${target_name}_c_compile_test.c")
  configure_file("${CMAKE_ROOT}/Modules/CMakeConfigurableFile.in" "${test_file}" @ONLY)
endfunction()

check_ext(@TARGET_NAME@ @TEST_FILE@ @SOURCE_DIR@ @SOURCES_LIST@)
```

It defines a rather generic function, but the way it is called will be configured by CMake, through `make_c_compile_tester`. The way I use `foreach()` permits to provide a list of files without having them defined in a single variable beforehand (it iterates from `${sources_list}` to the last argument given to the function).

Now, the function `make_c_compile_tester`:

```
function(make_c_compile_tester target_name)
  get_target_property(_src_list ${target_name} SOURCES)

  set(TARGET_NAME ${target_name})
  set(SOURCES_LIST ${_src_list})
  set(SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
  set(TEST_FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${target_name}_CCompileTest.c")
  configure_file(check_ext.cmake.in check_ext_${target_name}.cmake @ONLY)

  add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${TEST_FILE}
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -P "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/check_ext_${target_name}.cmake"
    WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}"
    DEPENDS ${_src_list}
    COMMENT "Generate program to check extensions."
  )
  add_custom_target(${target_name}-check-ext-depends DEPENDS "${TEST_FILE}")

  add_library(${target_name}-check-ext SHARED "${TEST_FILE}")
  add_dependencies(${target_name}-check-ext ${target_name}-check-ext-depends)

  add_dependencies(${target_name} ${target_name}-check-ext)
endfunction()
```

It generates a version of `check_ext.cmake` (called `check_ext_${target_name}.cmake`); triggering the processing of this script is wrapped in `add_custom_command()`. That way, CMake nows that this scripts generates `check_ext_${target_name}.cmake`, and depends on the sources files.

We then make a custom target `${target_name}-check-ext-depends` that simply depends on `check_ext_${target_name}.cmake`. Then, we create the library that compiles the `CCompileTest.c` file, and make it depend on `${target_name}-check-ext-depends`, so that the C file is updated when files are modified before being compiled. Finally, `${target_name}` depends on `${target_name}-check-ext`, so that the check library is compiled before the actual target.

I played with mostly dummy C files, so there may still be problems, but so far it seems to work, but for one case. I found out that when files are removed from the sources' list, the `CCompileTest.c` file is not updated. I think that is because generating this file depends on the sources' files, so removing a file from sources' list removes it from the dependencies as well, which means that the file is still up-to-date from a CMake perspective. I don't know how to fix this problem easily though.

Answer (score -1):

You don't say what it is you want to achieve.

1. Do you want to ensure that all *.h files are compiled with a C only compiler (with an error if C++ is used)?
2. Do you want to ensure that all *.h files are compilable with both C and C++ compilers?

Number 2 above is impossible in the general case. Identifiers that are reserved in C++ may be unreserved in C. For example, if your header has this:

```
static int new = 0;
```

Then that will compile in C but not in C++. The only thing that makes sense is possibly you want a *.h file that implements function name-mangling correct so that C functions declared in the header are visible to C++ callers. For example, you have a header that looks like so:

```
int foo (void); /* defined in a foo.c file somewhere
```

To achieve this you should write your header foo.h as follows (taking care to not use C++ reserved identifiers):

```
#ifdef H_FOO
#define H_FOO

... /* type declarations and definitions go here */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int foo (void);
/* Rest of your function declarations go here */

#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif


#endif
```

Comment: The question is not about achieving C/C++ interop, that is allready done (and requires a lot more than just avoiding name mangling). Its about making a CMake build tool for checking C/C++ interop. It is pretty clearly a CMake question about CMake things that just happens to build C/C++.

Comment: Why use the build tool? Using #ifdef __cplusplus #error would give you more accurate results that will work no matter what the file extension is.

Comment: Your codebase is written in either C or C++, right? Those macros work in both C and C++. If you later decide not to use C or C++ then your build script detection will be useless anyway.